# A matrix with positive principal minors has positive eigenvalues if it is real.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, not necessarily symmetric, and suppose all principal minors of $A$ are positive. How to show that any real eigenvalue of $A$ is must be positive?

Comment: Are you sure it's true ?

Comment: Yes. In fact, these matrices are called $P-$ matrices.

Comment: @JeanMarie This matrix doesn't have any real eigenvalue.

Comment: All right. Pardon me. I misread your question. I delete what I have said in order not to hide my error but not to confuse the reader in a century.

Comment: For reference: [p-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-matrix)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The wikipedia page does not say anything about the above question.

Comment: @babai sure, but it answers the question other readers may have of "what's a p-matrix". If it answered the question, I would make it an answer rather than a comment, or at least say that it was an answer.

Comment: The Wikipedia page doesn't give the equivalent criterion for P-matricies, the proof of that is exactly the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to find this result on some reference books on advanced linear algebra. I haven't any relevant book at hand, but this result seems obvious: as $A$ is a [P-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-matrix), its adjugate matrix has a positive diagonal; therefore, by [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) and by mathematical induction on the size of $A$, we have $\frac d{dt}\det(A+tI)=\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(A+tI))>0$ when $t\ge0$. Since $\det(A)$ is also positive, the polynomial $\det(A+tI)$ cannot have a positive real root and hence the characteristic polynomial $\det(tI-A)$ cannot have any negative real root.

Comment: "obvious" is a relative term, but in any case I'm impressed

Comment: Your obvious arguments seems quite complicated for me. For example, the first argument itsellf, the adjugate of a P-matrix has a positive diagonal. Why is it true? Can you please elaborate your answer in detail?

Comment: @Babai Let $A_1$ be the trailing principal submatrix of $A$ of size $n-1$. The first diagonal element of $\operatorname{adj}(A+tI)$ is then $\det(A_1+tI)$. By induction hypothesis, $\det A_1>0$ and all real eigenvalues (if any) of $A_1$ are nonnegative. Therefore $\det(A_1+tI)>0$ for every $t\ge0$. Simiilarly for every other diagonal element of $A+tI$.

Comment: @user1551 I understood your explanation. Very nice answer. Thank you.